# "System.timeoutException: Named Pipe ServiceStream" exception only in release mode, when starting a process using Process.Start

Tags: c#, exception, process, release

I am using a NappUpdate library to update my current C# application.Internally library uses Process.Start() to launch a process from my C# application.It works perfectly fine in debug mode.How ever in release mode, I get the following exception.

```
System.TimeoutException: The NamedPipeServerStream timedout waiting for a named pipe connection,
                         but the process has excited with exitcode: 
                         -532459699(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComException)
```

the following code is used to start a process

```
using (NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(syncProcessName, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
            p = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            if (p == null)
            {
                throw new ProcessStartFailedException("The process failed to start");
            }

            var asyncResult = pipe.BeginWaitForConnection(null, null);

            if (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(PIPE_TIMEOUT))
            {
                pipe.EndWaitForConnection(asyncResult);

                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(pipe, dto);
            }
            else if (p.HasExited)
            {
                Type exceptionType = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(p.ExitCode).GetType();

                throw new TimeoutException(string.Format("The NamedPipeServerStream timed out waiting for a named pipe connection, " +
                    "but the process has exited with exit code: {0} ({1})", p.ExitCode, exceptionType.FullName));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("The NamedPipeServerStream timed out waiting for a named pipe connection.");
            }
        }
```

Running my application on windows 10.
Can you please suggest me how to solve this exception in release mode?

Comment: Can you create a complete, minimal, verifiable example to demonstrate the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for the response.I will add code which is in simple and reproducible format.